# differentiating stone houses from barren rock in ArcGIS 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, remote-sensing, classification

I'm working in ArcGIS 9.3 trying to differentiate stone houses (often red brick roofs) from barren rock in a typical Mediterranean karst region via remote sensing. I have been using Landsat imagery. I have been trying out various band combinations, multiplying and filtering bands in unsupervised classification. So far no good.

Does anyone have some helpful suggestion?

Comment: Landsat images (30/30 meter resolution) for showing roof tops?  You may want to consider a higher resolution data source.

Comment: Thanx for the advice, but at the moment that is the only kind of imagery available to my budget :) The thing is that I need to differentiate the whole settlements from the surrounding area. I am not interested in particular features within the settlements (e.g. streets, houses etc.) but in general differences between urbanized areas and barren rock in their karst surroundings.

Comment: Good luck with that, even with 4 pulses per square metre LiDAR it's difficult to differentiate houses accurately. Perhaps it's not so much the houses you want but roads/tracks house gardens, these will have different signatures to rock though anything is going to be difficult to make out on 30m image! The best I could suggest given the resources you have is to try to get a trial of ERDAS or ENVI - these have much better classification utilities; with ArcGis you are trying to do it all the hard way.